# Preserve colors from vba when copy sheets to new workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code

```
Sub createPrice()
Set ThisWork = ThisWorkbook
strExt = ThisWork.Sheets("Main").Cells(1, 4).Value & "_" & Format(Now, "yyyy_mm_dd_hhmmss")
strSaveName = ThisWork.Path & "\" & strExt & ".xlsx"

ThisWork.Sheets(Array("Main", "Translations")).Copy
With ActiveWorkbook
    .Sheets("Translations").Visible = False
    .Colors = ThisWork.Colors
    .SaveAs strSaveName, FileFormat:=51
    .Close SaveChanges:=True
End With
End Sub
```

But Colors in new workbook is differs from original workbook

How to preserve colors?

Comment: Maybe try using `ThisWork.SaveCopyAs strSaveName` then open that file and delete the sheets you don't want.  That should give you an "exact"  copy including colors/themes.

Comment: I need do this fast as i have to do 100 prices at once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what color you are mentioning but try to change ThemeColorScheme with the following code:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Theme.ThemeColorScheme.Load ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Document Themes 15\Theme Colors\Office 2007 - 2010.xml")
```

You should change the path to your folder with Excel and change the Theme to one you need. List of themes you can find in Page Layout -> Colors. And you may need to change 'Document Themes 15' to 'Document Themes 14' for MS Excel 2010.

Or you can record the macro with changing theme in Page Layout -> Colors, it will generate code automatically.

Comment: Additional hints: An existing theme of a workbook (let's call it `wb1`) can be saved by `wb1.Theme.ThemeColorScheme.Save wb1.Path & "\whatever.xml"` and then be loaded into another workbook by above code. Instead of writing/loading an XML file you may copy each `MsoThemeColorSchemeIndex` by a simple loop: `For i = 1 to 12: wb2.Theme.ThemeColorScheme(i) = wb1.Theme.ThemeColorScheme(i): Next i`

Answer (score 3):

if you want the same color/theme of your workbook then you can use the below code.

```
Activeworkbook.Applytheme ( Thisworkbook.path & "\" & Thisworkbook.Name)
```

Happy Learning!

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered the same problem.
The way I deal with it is by using custom colors by setting manually the HEX or the RGB with the Colors dialog instead of using Theme color. No coding at all and it works just fine, as when VBA copies the sheet, it also copied the custom color.
[hex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcOLa.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note you are answering a very old and already answered question. Here is a guide on [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Though getting the path to the Color Scheme file is a good solution, it may not work if you're not going to be the one operating the spreadsheet - the other person may not have access to the specific color scheme file.
Alternatively, you can run a sub like the one below, which is a rough draft, to replace theme colors (which change with theme) by the actual color.

This sub will run over a selected range and "pin" the colors of its cells' interiors, borders, fonts etc., along with other theme-varying properties. It's far from perfect (changing border colors in this way, for instance, will create a black border if there are none), but it may be a good starting point for more detailed code.

Happy coding!

```
Sub FixColors()

Dim rng As Range

For Each rng In Selection

    With rng.Interior
        .Color = .Color
    End With
    With rng.Borders
        .Color = .Color
    End With
    With rng.Interior
        .PatternColor = .PatternColor
    End With
    With rng.Font
        .Color = .Color
        .Name = .Name
        .Size = .Size
    End With

Next

End Sub
```